# Should limit=all be used as a canonical in layered navigation?

Tags: layered-navigation, seo

I'm using the an SEO extension that allows me to add a canonical meta tag to layered navigation pages.

Next to this option, the extension states:

```
Don't use the "Current Category" value if the
"Allow All Products per Page" setting
(System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Frontend) is disabled.
```

In other words, enable the "view all" option in the catalog before using the option to add a canonical url to the layered navigation pages.

What this does then is make the canonical look like this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/category?limit=all"/>
```

Is this a good thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not a **Magento** question, I don't think this will help for categories.
The whole point of canonical is to help webmasters prevent duplicate content issues. So I guess this `<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/category"/>`
is fine.

Comment: After some more digging, I found this: https://youtu.be/njn8uXTWiGg?t=219